# Footprints for Sentinel-1 GRD imagery as GeoJSON or shapefiles

Tags: geojson, google-earth-engine

I made this script to create a visualization of the images available for an area of interest:

```
var north_demosite = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([13.18,58.53,16.99,61.33])
Map.addLayer(north_demosite, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'North Demosite');



// Filter the collection for the VV product from the descending track
var collectionVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(north_demosite)
    .select(['VV'])
    .filterDate('2017-03-15', '2017-09-15');

    //.filterDate('2018-03-15','2018-09-15');
print("printing VV collection")
print(collectionVV.size())
print(collectionVV);


// Filter the collection for the VH product from the descending track
var collectionVH = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(north_demosite)
    .select(['VH'])
    .filterDate('2017-03-15', '2017-09-15');

    //.filterDate('2018-03-15','2014-09-15');

print("printing VH collection")
print(collectionVH.size())
print(collectionVH);




function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection

  var id = image.id
  var image = ee.Image(image.id);
  var array = id.split("/");
  var date = array[2];
  var date = date.slice(0, 8);
  print(image)

  Map.addLayer(image)
}

collectionVH.evaluate(function(collectionVH) {  // use map on client-side
  collectionVH.features.map(addImage, {min: -25, max: 5})

})

collectionVV.evaluate(function(collectionVV) {  // use map on client-side
  collectionVV.features.map(addImage, {min: -25, max: 5})

})
```

It works fine! But I would need the information of this query in a GeoJSON or shapefile format. Is this possible? I haven't seen anything in the documentation of Google Earth Engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just export the ee.ImageCollection – image collection metadata are formatted as a [GeoJSON FeatureCollection object](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.3), including image geometry – for example, from your code:

```js
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: collectionVV,  // <-- ee.ImageCollection as input
  description: 'VV_footprints',
  fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'
});
```

This will include all image metadata in the resulting GeoJSON. If you want more control over what properties are included, you could map a function over the image collection to build an ee.FeatureCollection from each image's geometry and selected properties:

```
var fcVV = ee.FeatureCollection(collectionVV.map(function(img){
  return ee.Feature(img.geometry()).copyProperties(img, ['system:index']);
}));

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: fcVV,  // <-- ee.FeatureCollection as input
  description: 'VV_footprints',
  fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'
});
```

Comment: I'm confused about defining the feature - you return `ee.Feature(img)`, but doesn't a Feature cast require a geometry? Shouldn't it be `ee.Feature(geom)` instead?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it was a mix of two incomplete thoughts. I've edited the answer. Both of the code snippets you mention would work; in the `ee.Feature(img)` case, an image feature is returned, whose geometry is valid in the GeoJSON (or SHP) export, or you can export a feature whose geometry argument is the geometry property of the image. Or, you can just export the ee.ImageCollection as GeoJSON (or SHP) as I've described in the answer edit.